# Idiomatic ES6/ESnext way to clone an object while replacing one item with another using a different key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, clone, javascript-objects, ecmascript-next

If I want to do a shallow clone of an object without mutating while replacing adding new items or replacing items with new items using the same key I know I can use `Object.assign()`

```
const oldOb = { foo:10, bar:20 };
const newOb = Object.assign({}, oldOb, { bar:100 });
```

But what about if I want to replace `bar:20` with `baz:50`?

I know I can use `delete ob[bar]` but that's mutation, which I want to avoid.

Is there a neat functional programming way to achieve this with newer ES6/ES7/Babel features?

Comment: Are you willing to use lodash?

Comment: It seems like you could just use a `_.transform`

Comment: Why import an entire new library if we can also just examine the part of the code that makes this function? https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L13766

Comment: @DerekBrown: I'd like to use just Vanilla ES6/ES7 but feel free to submit your lodash answer and others are free to vote it up (-:

Comment: To be clear when you say ES7 you really mean ES2016+, yes? Because [there are only two new features added to ES7](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-7/info).

Comment: @FelixKling: Actually I mean pretty much any of the features that are definitely or very probably going to be, standardized in JS whether they're directly supported today or need a transpiler.

Comment: ES2015+ and ES.next then. The term ES7 was used for experimental features before ES7 was released. But it doesn't make sense to use the term for that now.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for updating the tags! (-:

Comment: IMO doing a simple `delete newOb.bar;` would be the cleanest solution. The intention is pretty clear with that one.

Comment: @FelixKling: In some contexts "pure" is preferred, as in React where you want to be able to compare by reference with `===` and `!==` so they always want to clone and avoid mutation.

Comment: @hippietrail: Mutating the cloned object is perfectly fine. You just shouldn't mutate the existing value / current state.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's true. There are probably some immutable purists out there though (-: Plus I feel it's a fun exercise in any case!

Comment: Sure... but in the long run, clear, simply solutions are better than "clever" ones ;)

Comment: I totally agree with felix here, just doing `delete obj[prop]` on the cloned object would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As mentioned by **@FelixKling** in the comments, just using `delete obj.key` on an already cloned object would be the simplest solution and is perfectly fine regarding the concept of immutability.

But if you want a more "complex" solution you could use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to clone the object and remove the desired property.

```js
const l = console.log;

function remove(o, p) {
  const { [p]: undefined, ...props } = o;
  return props;
}

const obj = { someProp: 'someValue', originalProperty: 'originalValue' };

l('remove:\n', remove(obj, 'originalProperty'));
l('original object: \n', obj);
```

If you want to have a `replace`, `rename` and `remove` functionality all in one method, then you could go for this one:

```js
const l = console.log;

function replace(o, p, n, v = o[p]) {
  const { [p]: undefined, ...props } = { ...o, ...(n ? { [n]: v } : {}) };
  return props;
}

const obj = { someProp: 'someValue', originalProperty: 'originalValue' };

l('replace:\n', replace(obj, 'originalProperty', 'replacedProperty', 'replacedValue'));
l('rename:\n', replace(obj, 'originalProperty', 'replacedProperty'));
l('remove:\n', replace(obj, 'originalProperty'));
l('original object:\n', obj);
```

A longer version for better understanding of the `replace` function:

```
function replace(
    obj,
    currentProperty,
    newProperty,
    newPropertyValue = obj[currentProperty]
  ) {
  let replacementObject = {};
  if(newProperty) {
    replacementObject = { [newProperty]: newPropertyValue };
  }
  const { [currentProperty]: undefined, ...remainingProperties } = Object.assign({}, obj, replacementObject);
  return remainingProperties;
}
```

Comment: But I want to replace the property, not just remove it. Obviously we can achieve that with a combination of your omit and an Object assign. I wonder if there's a one-liner though?

Comment: Added a simple replace function to my answer.

Comment: FWIW you could do `function replace(o, p, n, v=o[p]) {}` instead of `const rv = v !== undefined ? v : o[p];`.

Comment: @FelixKling yep, just added it. Thanks. I also add a longer version for better understanding.